# Incorrect unit price and total in line item

Tags: commerce

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or not.

As a requirement, my installation has to use Indonesian Rupiah as the default currency. The item in this example is worth Rp. 500.000 (we use period as separator as opposed to comma, and comma is used for decimal mark). As you can see in the attached screenshot, the unit price and the total for the line item are wrong, but the order total has the right number.

I checked other places (such as Drupal Commerce Reports), and I only found the wrong number in the individual order page and the edit page of the said item. I think it adds two extra zeroes for the cents, but the formatting is somehow messed up.

Please let me know if there's a quick patch for this. Thanks.

[image: incorrect unit price and total in line item]

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7LwI.png

Comment: "I think it adds two extra zeroes for the cents" - indeed that's what this module used to do in some places. Don't know if it's still the case. Anyway, if it behaves like that out of the box, it is a bug and should be reported via issue queue.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for confirming. I have reported it. Looks like this is the only place that still has this problem. Is there any quick fix that you know of?

Comment: Sorry, but no. You may try to look at your code for `* 100` or `/ 100`, but if it's a case of `* 100` *missing*, it will not be fun.